# Handling imbalanced data in Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, data-analysis

In the data, if the target feature is imbalanced say 2% good to 98% bad, and say 2% is 500 records, what if I use that 500 bad records plus only 500 good records from the 98% and train the model in machine learning.

My Question is will the Model generalize well with that 500 + 500 data as it is 50:50 good vs bad? and I do the selection of that good 500 records based multiple iterations to get the high accuracy as only 1000 records which will run faster in the machine to get the output.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is more suiatble for [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/][1]

Hi,

Hope above reference link will clear your concepts.

In case of working on unbalanced data its bad approach to check only one possibility, you have to try different method like collecting more data, creating data, changing the accuracy measurement (roc curve or different type of matrix) or sampling the input data.

Comment: All model will generalize well with 50:50 balance, my question is will the above work or not?

Comment: It will work, depending the relation between features.